# Editing row added to table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, edit

I found this post: [Editing and deleting a newly added table row using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276033/editing-and-deleting-a-newly-added-table-row-using-jquery) and that seemed like it was exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't get their suggested solution to work.

After making an ajax call, I add a new row to a table. The row looks similar to this:

```
<tr class="classRow" bgcolor="#EFE5D3" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em;">
    <td width="35px"><a class="classEditLink classAdminFormSubmit" name="33" href="#">Edit</a></td>
    <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteClass" name="deleteClasses[]" value="33" /></td>
    <td>CLASS101</td>
    <td>Class Description</td>
</tr>
```

The Edit link doesn't work until after a page refresh (I'm assuming that has something to due with the fact that it's not in the DOM immediately after it's added to the table). So, I needed to find a workaround, which lead me to the above-mentioned post.

I modified the code from there to look like this:

```
$('a').live('click', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).attr('class') == 'classAdminFormSubmit') {
        alert($(e.target).name());

        OpenEditDialog($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

The alert never fires, so I'm hoping it's just that my selector needs adjusting. I need to pass the selected anchor tag to the OpenEditDialog function.

Comment: I can't see the class : submitAddDocsToClass in the links?

Comment: Thanks, Liam. I changed it to check the correct class. Unfortunately that didn't fix my problem! :(

Comment: Liam, you kind of accidentally answered the question - or at least, lead me to the answer: After changing the class in my OP, I remembered that class needs to be added to the code that inserts the new row in the ajax call. Added that and viola! I can edit a freshly added row! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( 'a' ).live( 'click', function () {

    var $this = $( this );

    if ( $this.hasClass( 'classAdminFormSubmit' ) ) {

        alert( $this.attr( 'name' ) );

        OpenEditDialog( $this );

        return false;

    }

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, Jose. Could I have something else going on that may be preventing it from working? Is there maybe an alternative to .live()?

Comment: I have to take that previous statement back: I realized I wasn't adding the class to the code that inserts the row into the table. I added that and the dialog opens as it should.

Answer (score 0):

First, put a link in the row you just added, and give it a class, let's say it's `editRow`.
Second, use this code:

```
$('a.editRow').live('click', function(e){

    alert($(e.target).name());

    OpenEditDialog($(this));
    e.preventDefault(); // this is better than return false;
});
```

Comment: I already have a link in the clicked row and your code is awfully close to what I posted...

Comment: :) it may be close but `.attr('class') == 'aClass'` will not work with your link because the link has two classes.  My code should work.  Alternatively, you can use `hasClass`

Comment: My apologies, Milimetric. Your code does, indeed work fine, I just wasn't adding the class to the new row in the code that inserts it from the ajax call - fixed that and it works now.